# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'initializeBoard' before initialization

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```
const initialBoard = [];

const nestedMenuitems = ref([

    {
        label: 'Shipments',
      
        items: initializeBoard()
    },
  
]);
const initializeBoard = () => {
  stores.map((store) => initialBoard.push({lable: store.shop}));
//   stores.map(function(value, _key) {
//     initialBoard.push({lable: value.shop});
// });
  return initialBoard;
}
onMounted(() => {
    ApiService.getStores().then((data) => {
        stores.value = data;
//         stores.value.map(function(value, _key) {
            
//             list.push({lable: value.shop});

//      console.log(value.shop);
//    });
    //    stores.value.forEach((store) => { return {
            
    //  }});
     
    });
    
});
```

```
const nestedMenuitems = ref([
  
 {
        label: 'Shipments',
      
        items: [
            {
                label: 'Tracker',
                
            },
            {
                label: 'Map',
               
            },
            {
                label: 'Manage',
              
            }
        ]
    },


]);
```

this is i want to

but this line

```
        items: initializeBoard()
```

here  i fetch data in onMounted and then i call initializeBoard map function .the initializeBoard
call to  items: initializeBoard().but i get a error i get a error Uncaught (in promise)
ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'initializeBoard' before initialization how to solve thi problem?

Comment: The error means what it says, you access initializeBoard before it's defined.

Comment: @Aaron move the initializeBoard, before initializeBoard() call